# unknown system user 'mongodb' in statoverride file;

Tags: dpkg, mongodb

I am trying to download mongodb Compass, but I get this weird error in my terminal.
I think it is because I removed mongodb before, but I don't know how to fix this issue.
After I run `sudo apt upgrade` I get this error.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown system user 'mongodb' in statoverride file; the system user got removed
before the override, which is most probably a packaging bug, to recover you
can remove the override manually with dpkg-statoverride
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: `to recover you
can remove the override manually with dpkg-statoverride`

Comment: @Rinzwind,  dpkg-statoverride: error: need an action option

Answer (score 0):

run

```
sudo sed -i '/mongodb/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

and

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`, eg:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

and remove the two lines which refer to the mongodb user.